# AndroidManifest.xml error, how can I solve this problem?

Tags: android, flutter

```
Overlay manifest:package attribute declared at AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-37 value=(com.app.app)
has a different value=(com.app.app) declared in main manifest at AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-34
Suggestion: remove the overlay declaration at AndroidManifest.xml   and place it in the build.gradle:
    flavorName {
        applicationId = "com.app.app"
    }
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Overlay manifest:package attribute declared at AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-37 value=(com.app.app)
> has a different value=(com.app.app) declared in main manifest at AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-34
> Suggestion: remove the overlay declaration at AndroidManifest.xml   and place it in the build.gradle:
> flavorName {
> applicationId = "com.app.app"
> }

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 44s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

How i can fix this problem?

Comment: Go to `AndroidManifest.xml` line #2, remove the com.app.app and keep it in your gradle and see if it works.

Answer (score 5):

Try to search them and change your package name in the following locations:

1.) `src/profile/AndroidManifest.xml`

2.) `src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`

3.) `src/main/AdroidManifest.xml`

4.)

```
build.gradle .
defaultConfig {
applicationId
```

5.) `MainActivity.java` on `"package"`

If you want to know exactly how to achieve that, take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@skyblazar.cc/how-to-change-the-package-name-of-your-flutter-app-4529e6e6e6fc) page for further support.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution to this is by changing the package name in all these 5 files.

> 1.)  android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml

> 2.) android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

> 3.) android/app/src/profile/AdroidManifest.xml

> 4.) buildgradle file defaultConfig {applicationId: ""}

> 5.) MainActivity.java on "package" OR  MainActivity.kotlin

After modifying the above files, the  Flutter App run seamlessly any issues.